# The right way to override functions/views/controllers in external rails gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using some framework ([blacklight](https://rubygems.org/gems/blacklight)) that I need to change and extend to my own needs. Namely, I need to reimplement some functions, views and controllers. What I currently do is copying the file to a matching path in my working directory and make the changes inside the copied file. That way, my copied file overrides the original file in the gem. When a new version of the gem is released I might have to change my copied file accordingly. I don't like the way I solve the problem of modifying gems. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I know three ways, depending on specific situation.

The easiest is to overwrite at right place. For example, you can overwrite Devise's `current_user` in ApplicationController. Some methods apply to models, helpers. Just do it in right place.

The second is monkey patching. If there are no good place to overwrite and not too much things to change, you can monkey patch the gem's specific method in your app. The general practice is to put such monkey patching in `/lib`, exactly as per gem's module names, and the place to hook.

The third is to make your own fork of gem on github. Fork the gem, clone it in local, change whatever you need, push. If gem maintainer can accept your change, that's nice. If not, you can use your own version of the gem by set it in Gemfile

```
 gem 'some_geg', :git => 'git://github.com/my_repos/some_gem.git'
```

When there are updates in main, you can merge it in your own version.